# Add a datetime into a log file - CRON TASK

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I would like how can i get a log file : my_Log.log who have this infos :

31/07/2017 - 19:05:00 : ok

31/07/2017 - 19:10:00 : ok

31/07/2017 - 19:15:00 : ko

31/07/2017 - 19:20:00 : ok

I've tryed this command :

```
php -f /home/myrepo/Documents/CRON.php | /home/myrepo/Documents/datetime.sh > /home/myrepo/Documents/my_cron.log
```

into my file CRON.php i have this lines :

```
<?php 
echo "ok";
?>
```

into datetime.sh i have these lines :

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read x; do
        echo -n `date +%d/%m/%Y\ %H:%M:%S`;
        echo -n " ";
        echo $x;
    done
```

but into my_cron.log i have just a blank file with nothing inside...

Comment: Code has minor problems but there doesn't seem to be any obvious errors. Have you tested all these scripts interactively?

Comment: i tryed to run : php cron.php, it works. I tryed to run ls -l | ./datetime.sh. it works. I also tryed echo ''hello'' | ./datetime.sh > ouput.log 2>&1. it works. php cron.php | ./datetime.sh > log.log 2>&1 didn't work...

Comment: You might want to `php -f ... 2>&1 | ...` in your crontab.